# Vertically align Hyphend Text and Icon

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

i have a `<div>`that contains two `span`. One with a (longer) Text and One with a Icon. The text shall wrap (using hyphens) and the icon shall be vertically aligned right to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <style>

    tr > th > span.text {
        webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; -ms-hyphens: auto; -o-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto;
    }

    tr > th > span.icon {
        float: right; vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <table width="200px" style="table-layout:fixed">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <span class="text" lang="de">Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän</span>
                <span class="icon">
                    <img title="Icon" src="AufsteigendSortieren_d9d9d9.png">
                </span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span class="text" lang="de">Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän</span>
                <span class="icon">
                    <img title="Icon" src="AufsteigendSortieren_d9d9d9.png">
                </span>
            </th>
        <tr>
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

The resulting html should look like

```
Donaudampfschiff-
fahrtsgesellschafts   (icon here)
kapitän
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="text">Very very very very very long text.......</span>
    <span class="icon"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678134-sign-check-128.png" alt=""></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: table;
}

.container .text {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px;
}

.container .icon {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/4L126nps/

Comment: Doesn't work - the OP requires longer words to be broken using hyphens: http://jsfiddle.net/bupr4c2k/1/

Comment: unforunately this does not work in our case since the outer diff is actually a table. i update the question accordingly

Comment: @ChristianDietrich, the table is the only problem in my solution?

Comment: i dont know if it all fits together

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <style>

   .text {
        webkit-hyphens: manual; 
  -moz-hyphens: manual; 
  -ms-hyphens: manual; 
  -o-hyphens: manual; 
  hyphens: manual;
    }
 .icon {
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
  top: 25px;
 }
 .my-text{
  -webkit-hyphens: manual ;
  -moz-hyphens: manual ;
  -ms-hyphens: manual ;
  -o-hyphens: manual ;
  hyphens: manual ;
 }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <table style="width: 100px;">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <span class="text" lang="de">Donaudampfschiff&shy;fahrtsgesellschafts&shy;kapitän</span>
                <span class="icon">
                    <img title="Icon" src="AufsteigendSortieren_d9d9d9.png">
                </span>
            </th>
        <tr>
    </table>
 
 <div style="width:170px;">
     <span class="my-text">Donaudampfschiff&shy;fahrtsgesellschafts<img title="Icon" src="AufsteigendSortieren_d9d9d9.png">&shy;kapitän</span>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i actually want to use auto-hyphens. this works as long as the thing is not a inline-block

Comment: Well, if I put hyphens to auto it doesn't separate the words correctly as you want, you can try it yourself in example above.

Comment: in my first post i missed the lang attribute. if you add this it works in firefox.

Comment: Well It doesn't work for me, so i had to keep manual separators. Anyway, added 2nd variant.

Comment: hmmm, unfortunately i do not know the size of the image. additionally this does not work if haveing two column

Comment: Then you need to wrap those spans in 2 different divs and align them properly to each other

Comment: i hoped for a solution without changing the html structure